# jQuery .click() function isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My jQuery .click() function isn't working - it has to add text of button to string x and set totaldiv.text() to x, but when I click button it does nothing.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var x = "", y = "";
    var operator;
    var totaldiv = $("#total");
    totaldiv.text("0");
    $("#numbers button").click(function(){
        x += $(this).text();
        totaldiv.text(x);
    });
});
```

My html if it's needed:

```
<div id="numbers">
    <button class="btn">1</button>
    <button class="btn">2</button>
    <button class="btn">3</button>
    <button class="btn">4</button>
    <button class="btn">5</button>
    <button class="btn">6</button>
    <button class="btn">7</button>
    <button class="btn">8</button>
    <button class="btn">9</button>
    <button class="btn">0</button>      
</div>
<div id="total">
</div>
```

Comment: `$(#total);` => `$("#total");`.

Comment: Taking a look at the console is always useful.

Comment: fixed still doesn't work.

Comment: [Works for me](https://jsfiddle.net/dxwx09pz/).

Comment: it does work; if you're testing this on something like JSFiddle, make sure you've included jQuery.

Comment: I've included jQuery, I don't know why it's not working.

Comment: It turned out that I have included jQuery-ui.js instead of jQuery.min.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well if you mean why is it adding the number on so 2, 3, 4 would be 234 instead of 9. It's because they are strings.

use this line instead...
var x = 0;
x += parseInt($(this).text());

otherwise it works if you include jQuery as said in the comments

Comment: It turned out that I have included jQuery-ui.js instead of jQuery.min.js thank you for trying to help